# scaffolding and updating attributes manually in ruby on rails howto?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding

I was wondering if anyone knew how to update the files (adding/removing/updating an attribute) produced by using the scaffold generator in ruby on rails.

For example:

scaffold student name:string lastname:string

so this will create a the associate files (controller,view,etc) with name and lastname as string attributes.  When you db:migrate the project, it'll create the table in the database.  However, say I want to update whether it be update it with an addition attribue (ex. studenId:integer) or if its removing or updating an attribute, how do you do that?

I tired just updating the generated files, but when I do that db:migrate it still sets the schema that is generated to what is in the table.  Is there a built in script in rails that will update the table?

Any advise appreciated?
Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need new migration file for new attributes, from console:

```
$ script/gnerate migration add_sudentid_to_sudent
```

it will generate your_app/db/migrate/8293898391_add_sudentid_to_sudent.rb,  spicify in this file your new attributes:

```
def self.up
  add_column :sudents, :studentId, :integer
end

def self.down
 remove_column :students, :studentsId
end
```

after that, back to console:

```
$  rake db:migrate
```

and than you can edit your views, model, controller files and use new attribute

Answer (score 2):

Full command in this example:

```
$ rails generate migration add_studentid_to_student
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi Try `ruby script/destroy scaffold student` and then `ruby script/generate scaffold student`

Answer (score 1):

also try reading up on rails migrations, for dropping/updating table columns.
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html